# How many episodes do I need for the perfect learn in openai_ros turtlebot example

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros/TurtleBot2%20with%20openai_ros) related with open_ai.
The code is working well.

But although I made the turtlebot learned more than 35K episodes, it still can not pass through the first corner yet.

So, I want to ask that how many episodes averagely I need for making this robot learned completely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305064/how-many-episodes-do-i-need-for-the-perfect-learn-in-openai_ros-turtlebot-example/) by [danny p](https://answers.ros.org/users/37750/danny-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-10-24**:
Please have a look at this new [ROS Developers Live Class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT1EQN2U5WE) where we actually train the Turtlebot for moving around the maze using a DQNN with Keras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The learning algorithm used in the examples of openai_ros tutorials is a very simple `Q-learning` implementation (only provided as an example). It is very unlikely that it will work for that task.

However, you can easily change the learning algorithm by any other just touching on the `start_training.py` script.
Today we have this free [ROS Developers Live Class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtPPEi5oUa4) where we teach how to change the algorithms in a very simple way. We will use `DeepQlearning` algorithms that we find on the OpenAI website and we show how to adapt them with a very few steps to work in the `openai_ros` based robotic task.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0